# How to get all files ending with the extension "_\<fileNum>of\<totalFileNum>" and sometimes without?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, file

I am working on exporting data into a file which sometimes requires more than one file to fit everything in. In this case, the file name is appended to with "_<fileNum>of<totalFileNum>". The problem comes up when the user wants to import the file back into the system.

The user specifies a file, and the program should be able to tell if it is a part of a larger collection of files (by looking at if it ends with "_of"). I used the following code to get all the files ending with the extension as follows:

```
string fileName = "example_file_1of4";    
string[] deploymentFiles = Directory.GetFiles( srcDir, $"{fileName}_*of*", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly );
```

This obviosly does not work since it appends the "_<>of<>" at the end of the file which already has the extention. How could I make this example work when I do not know the exact number of digits there could be in the file name?

This also needs to work when there is only a single file which does not have the "_<fileNum>of<totalFileNum>" extension.

Thanks

Comment: *How could I make this example work* - `GetFiles(.., $"{filename}*")` and then `Regex.IsMatch(fullfilename, @"_\d+of\d+")` on the results to detect if it's part of a set

Comment: Regex was definitely the way to go, thank you! Here is the solution I used: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70279606/how-to-extract-name-from-a-file-name-in-the-form-name-filenumoffilenumtota

Comment: Welcome! I closed this as a duplicate of that because that does all this was asking and more